# Can't get rating and reviewer fields in Facebook Graph Explorer

Tags: facebook, graph, explorer, review

Try to use Graph API Explorer and get my page reviews, use this URL

```
111280982309/ratings?fields=reviewer{id,name,picture.width(120).height(120)},created_time,rating,recommendation_type,review_text,open_graph_story{id}
```

but can't get rating and reviewer fields

Here are the results :

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "created_time": "2017-12-08T12:27:33+0000",
      "recommendation_type": "positive",
      "review_text": "Très professionnels, s'adaptent à toutes les situations",
      "open_graph_story": {
        "id": "1655894074569809"
      }
    },
    ...
    {
      "created_time": "2013-11-24T06:14:30+0000",
      "recommendation_type": "positive",
      "open_graph_story": {
        "id": "1020383498134514"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

with all the permission needed :

```
pages_show_list
pages_read_engagement
pages_read_user_content
public_profile
```

After multiple hours of research, I do not find any solutions...
My app is business type (and there is no more live or dev mode button)
The app is approuved for all the permission above

Comment: i assume you cannot get the reviewer for privacy reasons. why would you need the name of the users anyway?

Comment: Business apps don’t have dev mode/live mode any more, they have access levels now: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/overview/access-levels/ - which one is yours?

Comment: I want the reviewer name and rating to display all the reviews in a grid or in a carousel.

Comment: My app has advanced access ('approuved by facebook) for pages_show_list,
pages_read_engagement, pages_read_user_content

Comment: Not all reviews have a rating, yours here appear to have the recommendation_type of positive or negative. Checking the reviews on https://www.facebook.com/agence.orealys/reviews/, I don’t see any that had an actual star rating, and when I try to add a new one, I also only get the choice between whether I recommend this page or not, it does not ask me for any star rating.

Comment: My facebook page is just an example. The results is the same with other pages, and some reviews have no rating, but the problem is that reviewer name or profile picture doesn't show anyway